# Problems creating classes in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Each class I create in a java project in Eclipse does something strange. When I create a new file for the class it appears as if the class I had originally and the class I subsequently created as another file are identical except for the name.

This is for Eclipse on MacOS. I am very new to programming so I am not sure if I did something wrong, as I have not seen anyone with this problem.

I expected that each class I created as a new file would be able to have different code written into it without having it be overwritten with other code from the most recently edited file in that project.

Comment: Please show a screenshot of what you're talking about.

Comment: Which _Eclipse_ version are you using?

Comment: I just reopened eclipse and for some reason I am not having this problem anymore. I am not sure why as I did not change anything, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What steps do you use for creating the class? 
I use to right-click on the package in the Package Explorer and the new --> Class  and answer the Wizards questions. Used to work for me. 
Ho do you do it?